# How can i use a html file which is in a folder and that folder is in public folder so how to use that as a component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can i use a html file which is in a folder and that folder is in public folder so how to use that as a component in reactjs.that bg.html file is the file which i want to use it as a component becuase that file is a animation which i want to use it as my website background to how to do that i want to use that bg.html file as a component in my HeroHome.jsx file.
[image]

## HeroHome.jsx file code in which i want to use my bg.html file as a component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from '../utils/Modal';

import HeroImage from '../images/hero-image.png';

function HeroHome() {

  const [videoModalOpen, setVideoModalOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section className="relative">

      {/* Illustration behind hero content */}
      <div className="absolute left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 bottom-0 pointer-events-none" aria-hidden="true">
      <svg width="1360" height="578" viewBox="0 0 1360 578" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="illustration-01">
              <stop stopColor="#FFF" offset="0%" />
              <stop stopColor="#EAEAEA" offset="77.402%" />
              <stop stopColor="#DFDFDF" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <g fill="url(#illustration-01)" fillRule="evenodd">
            <circle cx="1232" cy="128" r="128" />
            <circle cx="155" cy="443" r="64" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">

        {/* Hero content */}
        <div className="pt-32 pb-12 md:pt-40 md:pb-20">

          {/* Section header */}
          <div className="text-center pb-12 md:pb-16">
            <h1 className="text-5xl md:text-6xl font-extrabold leading-tighter tracking-tighter mb-4" data-aos="zoom-y-out">Make your website <span className="bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-teal-400">wonderful</span></h1>
            <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto">
              <p className="text-xl text-gray-600 mb-8" data-aos="zoom-y-out" data-aos-delay="150">Our landing page template works on all devices, so you only have to set it up once, and get beautiful results forever.</p>
              <div className="max-w-xs mx-auto sm:max-w-none sm:flex sm:justify-center" data-aos="zoom-y-out" data-aos-delay="300">
                <div>
                  <a className="btn text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 w-full mb-4 sm:w-auto sm:mb-0" href="#0">Start free trial</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <a className="btn text-white bg-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-800 w-full sm:w-auto sm:ml-4" href="#0">Learn more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* Hero image */}
          <div>
            <div className="relative flex justify-center mb-8" data-aos="zoom-y-out" data-aos-delay="450">
              <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
                <img className="mx-auto" src={HeroImage} width="768" height="432" alt="Hero" />
                <svg className="absolute inset-0 max-w-full mx-auto md:max-w-none h-auto" width="768" height="432" viewBox="0 0 768 432" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                  <defs>
                    <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="hero-ill-a">
                      <stop stopColor="#FFF" offset="0%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#EAEAEA" offset="77.402%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#DFDFDF" offset="100%" />
                    </linearGradient>
                    <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="99.24%" id="hero-ill-b">
                      <stop stopColor="#FFF" offset="0%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#EAEAEA" offset="48.57%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#DFDFDF" stopOpacity="0" offset="100%" />
                    </linearGradient>
                    <radialGradient cx="21.152%" cy="86.063%" fx="21.152%" fy="86.063%" r="79.941%" id="hero-ill-e">
                      <stop stopColor="#4FD1C5" offset="0%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#81E6D9" offset="25.871%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#338CF5" offset="100%" />
                    </radialGradient>
                    <circle id="hero-ill-d" cx="384" cy="216" r="64" />
                  </defs>
                  <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                    <circle fillOpacity=".04" fill="url(#hero-ill-a)" cx="384" cy="216" r="128" />
                    <circle fillOpacity=".16" fill="url(#hero-ill-b)" cx="384" cy="216" r="96" />
                    <g fillRule="nonzero">
                      <use fill="#000" xlinkHref="#hero-ill-d" />
                      <use fill="url(#hero-ill-e)" xlinkHref="#hero-ill-d" />
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <button className="absolute top-full flex items-center transform -translate-y-1/2 bg-white rounded-full font-medium group p-4 shadow-lg" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); setVideoModalOpen(true); }} aria-controls="modal">
                <svg className="w-6 h-6 fill-current text-gray-400 group-hover:text-blue-600 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M12 22c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10S17.523 2 12 2 2 6.477 2 12s4.477 10 10 10zm0 2C5.373 24 0 18.627 0 12S5.373 0 12 0s12 5.373 12 12-5.373 12-12 12z" />
                  <path d="M10 17l6-5-6-5z" />
                </svg>
                <span className="ml-3">Watch the full video (2 min)</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            {/* Modal */}
            <Modal id="modal" ariaLabel="modal-headline" show={videoModalOpen} handleClose={() => setVideoModalOpen(false)}>
              <div className="relative pb-9/16">
                <iframe className="absolute w-full h-full" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/174002812" title="Video" allowFullScreen></iframe>
              </div>
            </Modal>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default HeroHome;
```

## bg.html file which has animation which i want to use it on my HeroHome.jsx file as a component

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Jump to Hyperspace v2 ⭐️ (mousedown/touchstart)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused! in the public folder there is no `index.html` so do you want to use `bg.html` as `index.html`??

Comment: @monim index.html file is also their in the project folder but i have just created public folder for this bg.html file so tell how to use that i can delte publiuc folder a